# ProgressBar while receiving Recyclerview data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I come to ask you for guidance with this, I have a recycler view, and what I want is that while the recyclerview is filled from the cloud firebase, a circular progressBar appears, and as soon as it loads, it disappears and the Recyclerview is loaded. I have already tried seeing various orientations around here but I cannot find it, with my code the progressbar is placed in a GONE way immediately, I imagine that you have to implement a ** CALLBACK ** or something like that, but no idea, I would appreciate that They will guide me a little with that of the CALLBACK, to see how I could implement it.

Borrow a photo and video from other users so they understand what I want to do

Demo Imagen --->   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbLSi.png

Here is a video with what I want ---> [Video](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsQkFTSm13bUFLX00/components-progressactivity-behavior-Loading_Files_Circular_xhdpi_003.webm)

And here is the code that I am using

-------------------- Layout ------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MasvotingFragment">


    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

--------------------- Java ---------------------------

```
public class MasvotingFragment extends Fragment {

    public MasvotingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private FirebaseFirestore mDatabase;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private Parcelable listState;
    private RecyclerViewMasvotados mAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_masvoting, container, false);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        basedatocall();

        if(listState!=null){

            listState = Objects.requireNonNull(savedInstanceState).getParcelable("ListState");
        }


    }

    private void basedatocall() {


        Query query = mDatabase.collection("Post")
                .orderBy("totales", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<masvotados> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<masvotados>()
                .setQuery(query, masvotados.class).build();


        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMasvotados(options);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAdapter.startListening();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
        mAdapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAdapter !=null){
            mAdapter.stopListening();
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putParcelable("ListState", Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).onSaveInstanceState());
    }

}
```

In advance Thank you all for your help, a hug

Comment: When you start querying for your data on Firestore your progressbar is visible, and only when you retrieve the data you and that you made sure the data is not null you hide your progressbar and show your recyclerview. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630834/6074224) could be a first step

Comment: Perfect, with your recommendation I have succeeded, Thank you